# I can't use properly the replace command in python

Tags: python, replace, bioinformatics, rosalind

I'm new on the platform:

I have a doubt about the use of the replace command.

Here is my code and what I need to do:
The thing is that I need to replace a substring with a string sequence.

For example:
from: Hitacoworld to Hiworld.
The thing is that I part from a dictionary with the string and substrings and I don't know how to get the string without the substring part. I use the command replace this way:

```
ntdna = ''

ntdna += string.replace(seqs[element],'',)
```

Where `'string'` is my string and `'seqs[element]'` are the substrings that I want to remove from the string, but the problem is that when I see the outcome I'm not getting the right string, so I think the problem is in the use of the replace, any hint or something I could use? Ty in advance, I'm lost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weV33.png)

Comment: You want this string to get smaller and smaller as it matches more subsequences, right?  So why do you built `ntdna` as a new variable?  Why don't you just keep reducing `string`, as in `string = string.replace(seqs[element,''))`?  And please delete the `from os import replace` line.  That `replace` is a file rename function.  It has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: @TimRoberts ty so much, editing that maked the code work, and the replace thing was written itself when I write replace, i didn't even notice that